# Entity Framework join ignore all my includes

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Supose this method

```
  private IQueryable<FactureAnonyme> RequeteFacture(params Expression<Func<Facture, object>>[] includes)
  {
     return from f in _contexte.Set<Facture>().Include(includes)
            from mf in f.MontantsFacture.OfType<MontantFrais>().DefaultIfEmpty()
            from mt in f.MontantsFacture.OfType<MontantTaxeUnit>().DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new FactureAnonyme
            {
               Id = f.Id,
               Facture = f,
               MontantsFrais = mf,
               MontantsTaxeUnit = mt,
               Frais = mf.Frais,
               TaxeUnitaire = mt.TaxeUnitaire,
               Taxe = mt.TaxeUnitaire.Taxe
            };
  }
```

When i get my object "Facture" query ignore all my include why? And how can I do to include my navigation property for my object Facture.

N.B. I don't want to use the Lazy Loading

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [by design](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/347543/entity-framework-eager-loading-not-working-in-some-projection-scenarios). `Include` is lost once you start using custom joins or projections. You must expose properties on your projected type and manually fill them in projection.

Comment: It's not very user friendly. I would have preferred that the compiler gets a mistake, the default is assumed that the request is really do the job.

Comment: Ok, does it have a workaround for this problem? I try a lot of solution but nothing working... I know how to do this with SQL but with EF it's really a nightmare!

Comment: It doesn't have workaround. You either want entity access where you can use `Include` (= direct entity query) or you want special projected data where you must load everything by yourselves.